# Routing error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, laravel

There is a route:

```
Route::get('message/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'HomeController@edit', 'as' => 'message.edit'])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

Code in my HomeController:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $data = [
        'title' => 'page',
        'pagetitle' => 'page',
        'message' => Message::find($id)
    ];

    return view('pages.messages.edit', $data);
}
```

And a view:

```
@extends('index')
@section('content')
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'message.edit']) !!}
         @include('_common._form')
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

And I get this error:

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: message.edit] [URI: message/{id}/edit]. (View: C:\OpenServer\domains\laravel\book\resources\views\pages\messages\edit.blade.php)
```

Where is the problem?
I tried to remove form from code, it works well. So it means that something wrong with the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an ID, because your route demands it.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Try this:   `{!! Form::open(['route' => ['message.edit', $theId]]) !!}` where `$theId` should be real ID. For example, you usually use `show` method to call a view which displays a form, so you should just pass this ID from `show($id)` method to a view and then pass it to `edit($id)` method as I showed before.

Comment: I want to get this ID from my edit method in HomeController

Comment: But you must give an ID to use edit method. Look at your edit method: `public function edit($id)` - it demands $id. Look at your route: `message/{id}/edit` - it demands ID too.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like the following:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['message.edit', $message]]) !!}
```